# Why does my class not behave exactly like the overridden base class?

Tags: c#, combobox, overriding, settings, application-settings

My application has a `ComboBox` and had an application setting `myStrings` of the type `System.Collections.Specialized.StringCollection`. I bound the `ComboBox.ItemSource` to `Properties.Settings.Default.myStrings`. The ComboBox displayed the items of myStrings, as I planned.

Unfortunately the ComboBox did not update the items, when myStrings changed. So I tried to create a new class `CustomStringCollection` that overrides StringCollection and implements `INotifyPropertyChanged`.

**The setting is not properly saved. I did expect that `CustomStringCollection : StringCollection` does behave exactly like it's base class, including when it is saved. Why is it not the same?**

This is the settings file and you can see that myStrings-values are saved, but myCustomStringCollection-values are not:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<configuration>
    …
    <userSettings>
        <comboBoxDataBinding.Properties.Settings>
            <setting name="myStrings" serializeAs="Xml">
                <value>
                    <ArrayOfString xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
                        xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">
                        <string>Banana</string>
                    </ArrayOfString>
                </value>
            </setting>
            <setting name="myCustomStringCollection" serializeAs="Xml">
                <value />
            </setting>
        </comboBoxDataBinding.Properties.Settings>
    </userSettings>
</configuration>
```

This is the class comboBoxDataBinding:

```
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Configuration;
using System.Reflection;

namespace comboBoxDataBinding {
    [DefaultMember("Item")]
    [SettingsSerializeAs(SettingsSerializeAs.Xml)]
    class CustomStringCollection : System.Collections.Specialized.StringCollection, INotifyPropertyChanged {
        public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;

        private void OnPropertyChanged(string v) {
            if (PropertyChanged != null) {
                PropertyChanged(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(v));
            }
        }
    }
}
```

And this is how I saved those settings:

```
Properties.Settings.Default.myStrings.Add("Banana");
Properties.Settings.Default.myCustomStringCollection.Add("Banana");
Properties.Settings.Default.Save();
```

Comment: I suppose you have to implement `INotifyCollectionChanged`, not `INotifyPropertyChanged`.

Comment: Shouldn't you mark the class with the `[Serializable]` attribute?

Comment: dymanoid, thanks for the hint! @PeterDuniho, are attributes not inherited? I also tried `[SettingsSerializeAs(SettingsSerializeAs.Xml)]`. Is there a difference to `[serializable]`? Both do not work.